# Bamboo with Android Project: The SDK directory does not exist

Tags: android, amazon-ec2, bamboo

I use Bamboo with an EC2 instance (with Ubuntu).

When the task to build my android project from Bamboo is called, I have this error:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
error   31-Dec-2014 06:23:16    > The SDK directory '/home/android/android-sdk-linux' does not exist.
```

Unfortunately this directory exits!

I can't understand why this error!

Thank you for your help guys!

Comment: can you show me the output for below commands: `ls -ld /home/andriod` and `ls -ld /home/android/android-sdk-linux`.

Answer (score 0):

In Creation of task for the plan, just provide the android sdk location (on CI server) in Environment variables. 
Check the screen shot attached, in my case it was placed at : "ANDROID_HOME="C:\Android\sdk"[image]"

Once this is done, just run the plan

Comment: Can you share what your executable command path for "Android Clean Build"?